# Can't download maven help plugin

Tags: maven, maven-2

Executing the following command

> mvn help:effective-pom

results in this error

```
Downloading: http://mavenrepo.xxx.xxx/nexus/content/groups/development/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-help-plugin/2.2.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-help-plugin-2.2.1-20161111.071815-5788.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Error building POM (may not be this project's POM).


Project ID: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin

Reason: POM 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin' not found in repository: Unable to locate resource in repository

  org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin:pom:2.2.1-20161111.071815-5788

from the specified remote repositories:
  nexus (http://mavenrepo.xxx.xxx/nexus/content/groups/development)

 for project org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin
```

What's confusing me is the datetime stamp added to the artifact being downloaded. The plugin is in the repostitory but without any datetime stamp.

What am I doing wrong, how do I resolve this?

EDIT

Solved this by finding a random repo that had the exact version of the maven-help-plugin that my maven was inisting on downloading. Nothing I tried the make my maven download a different version worked. I'm wondering if the maven-help-plugin is special in some way.

Thanks for everyone who contributed.

Comment: Have you checked the "maven-metadata.xml" file in the nexus repo in the "maven-help-plugin" folder? What is under "<versions>"?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to pass plugin version through the command line like

`mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin:3.1.0:effective-pom`

You can also try removing the plugin from the local m2 folder. (_maven.repositories file inside the plugin folder may cause issues like this.)

Also as a short term solution, you can download the plugin manually and add it to your local repo, and delete the _maven.repositories file. and use mvn -o help:effective-pom coomand to run it in offline mod. It wont look to the repo this way

Comment: Thanks but specifiying a specific version doesn't help. `mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin:2.2.1-SNAPSHOT` or `mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin:2.2` produce exactly the same error message as above. Seem that maven ignores the request for a specific version, and is still insisting on 2.2.1-SNAPSHOT-20161111.071815-5788. Deleting the local repo folder didn't help either.

Comment: @john 1.Can you use any other version of the plugin. 2. Does this error happens on other computers. 3. You refer to a snapshot version, check if the repository you refer to,  is a snapshot repository. There is confiuration related to this https://maven.apache.org/guides/development/guide-testing-development-plugins.html

Comment: I can't use any other version of the plugin as explained in the comment above. It doesn't matter what version I request maven always tries to get the same version 2.2.1-SNAPSHOT-20161111.071815-5788 which isn't in the repo, but 2.2.1-SNAPSHOT is. I don't care what version I use, I just want the command `mvn help:effective-pom` to work but it doesn't for some unknown reason.

Comment: @john Only thing that comes to mind, the plugin is defined in your parent pom in the plugin management section as this version. (or in your current pom ) try adding the plugin with specific version in your current pom if you have not tried. https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/plugin-info.html

Comment: @john Also as a short term solution, you can download the plugin manually and add it to your local repo, and delete the _maven.repositories file. and use mvn -o help:effective-pom coomand to run it in offline mod. It wont look to the repo this way